# Macbook Pro M1 battery health dropped very rapidly

Tags: battery, apple-silicon

I purchased my MBP M1 at July 2021. It started dropping battery health very quickly, and I feel it happened faster after the Monterey update. It shows 93% in the settings and when I installed coconut battery, the number was terrifying.

Why is this happening and what should I do about it?

[image]

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store or wherever you bought it. 80% of original capacity is the point at which Apple will consider a battery for replacement, but that's usually after years of use. If there is a problem, you should be able to get it fixed (or a replacement Mac) free -- depending on the consumer law protections in your area.